# Use SPARQL property path on DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'd like to find out if property paths exist between two entities on DBpedia. This is a sample query that I tried on `snorql`:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
:Braveheart (:|!:)* :Mel_Gibson
}
LIMIT 100
```

The queries runs into a memory error:

```
Virtuoso 42000 Error TN...: Exceeded 1000000000 bytes in transitive temp memory. use t_distinct, t_max or more T_MAX_memory options to limit the search or increase the pool SPARQL query: define sql:big-data-const 0 #output-format:application/sparql-results+json define input:default-graph-uri PREFIX owl: PREFIX xsd: PREFIX rdfs: PREFIX rdf: PREFIX foaf: PREFIX dc: PREFIX : PREFIX dbpedia2: PREFIX dbpedia: PREFIX skos: SELECT * WHERE { :Braveheart (:|!:)* :Mel_Gibson } LIMIT 100
```

I suspect someone's going to suggest setting up a local dbpedia mirror. If that's the case, I'd love some detailed steps on how to do so.

Comment: Your query is quite expensive since it looks for all paths between two nodes in a large RDF graph. Sure, you could set up your own Virtuoso and load DBpedia on your local machine. But I'm wondering whether this will help if you don't have a machine with more resources than the one on which the public DBpedia is hosted.

Comment: Detailed steps: https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/11/23/setting-up-a-linked-data-mirror-from-rdf-dumps-dbpedia-2015-04-freebase-wikidata-linkedgeodata-with-virtuoso-7-2-1-and-docker-optional/

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is a bit wrong for what you're trying to answer... also as there are no variables in it `select *` can't project anything out (i'd consider it a bug to even compile this), so let me [rephrase your query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=ASK%20%7B%20dbr%3ABraveheart%20%28%3C%3E%7C%21%3C%3E%29%2B%20dbr%3AMel_Gibson%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) to

```
ASK { dbr:Braveheart (<>|!<>)+ dbr:Mel_Gibson }
```

Sadly that query errs with the same problem you described.

While i agree, that complicated should be executed against local endpoints, the above query isn't complicated at all, especially considering that there are several [direct edges between the two nodes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20*%20%7B%20dbr%3ABraveheart%20%3Fp%20dbr%3AMel_Gibson%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on):

```
SELECT * { dbr:Braveheart ?p dbr:Mel_Gibson }
```

I consider this a bug in Virtuoso's query planner and reported it: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/641

Having said all that, i'd like to point out that in real cases you're probably interested in paths that don't only point forward. The direction of edges greatly depends on modelling. So consider using queries like these instead:

```
ASK { dbr:Braveheart ((<>|!<>)|^(<>|!<>))+ dbr:Mel_Gibson }
```

The expression says follow any edge in their direction or against it (`^`) for at least one step. (Yes, i also wonder why property paths didn't a short syntax for arbitrary edges ;) )

Comment: ASK only returns a `true` or `false`, right? What I want to do is view all property paths between two nodes. Given the need, isn't SELCT the appropriate option?

Comment: then you need at least one intermediate variable to "project" out. Sadly property paths don't allow variables in them, so there's nothing to project. You could try `select distinct * { dbr:Braveheart (<#>|!<#>)* ?n . ?n ?p ?n2 . ?n2 (<#>|!<#>)* dbr:Mel_Gibson . }`, but that's even worse :D

Answer (score 0):

Spinning off @JörnHees's answer, a couple of points:

1. `<>` is an invalid predicate identifier.  For Virtuoso, `<>` identifies a document (Location of Content that returns `200 OK` on HTTP `GET`) which is why `<#>` or `<#this>` work. This isn't a parsing issue since it has more to do with the semantics of an identifier.
2. The public DBpedia endpoint isn't configured to accept that kind of query, hence the error.

Using `<#this>` rather than `<>`, we have --

```
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
ASK { dbpedia:Braveheart (<#this>|!<#this>)+ dbpedia:Mel_Gibson }
```

Two alternative instances, both hosted by [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) (my employer, and producer of [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/)), that produce solutions for that query:

- [DBpedia-Live instance](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0AASK%20%7B%20dbpedia%3ABraveheart%20%28%3C%23this%3E%7C%21%3C%23this%3E%29%2B%20dbpedia%3AMel_Gibson%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)
- [LOD Cloud Cache instance](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%20%0D%0AASK%20%7B%20dbpedia%3ABraveheart%20%28%3C%23this%3E%7C%21%3C%23this%3E%29%2B%20dbpedia%3AMel_Gibson%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)